# How to extract all text's link and other properties form html?

Tags: java, list, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Note, if it is single element I can extract but I need to extract all of them together.

Hi I am trying to extract the text and link from a list of items from a page using Selenium and Java. I am able to extract all link text but facing issue to figure out the link text. The html code looks like below:

```
<div class="col-12">
        <a href="/category/agricultural-products-service">
                <img src="/assets/images/icon/1.jpg" alt="icon" class="img-fluid category_icon">
                    <h5 class="category_title">Agricultural </h5>
        </a>
 </div>
<div class="col-12">
        <a href="/category/products-service">
                <img src="/assets/images/icon/7.jpg" alt="icon" class="img-fluid category_icon">
                    <h5 class="category_title">Products</h5>
        </a>
 </div>
```

Using `h5` I can extract all the elements but I need to extract all href of those elements

Comment: Have you tried to gather all div's with the class via an xPath search?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To extract text or link or any other attribute value from several web elements you need to collect all these elements in a list and then to iterate over the list extracting the desired value from each web element object.
As following:

```java
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.tagName("h5"));
for(WebElement element : elements){
    String value = element.getText();
    System.out.println(value);
}
```

This will give you all the links there

```java
List<WebElement> links = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".top_cat a"));
for(WebElement link : links){
    String value = link.getAttribute("href");
    System.out.println(value);
}
```

On this specific page the structure is:
There are several blocks defined by `class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 border all_cat"` elements. Inside each such block several links and titles. Each `a` is below the `class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 border all_cat"` element and the title is below it `a` element. So, extracting the links and titles here can be done as following:

```java
List<WebElement> blocks = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".all_cat"));
for(WebElement block : blocks){
    List<WebElement> links = block.findElements(By.xpath(".//a"));
    for(WebElement link : links){
        String linkValue = link.getAttribute("href");
        System.out.println("The link is " + linkValue);
        WebElement title = block.findElements(By.xpath(".//h5"));
        String titleValue = title.getText();
        System.out.println("The title is " + titleValue);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I was able to extract the text using h5. But I faced difficulties to extract the href links. Any suggestion?

Comment: Sure. Can you share a link to that page?

Comment: https://addressbazar.com/category    I was trying to exact all catergory name, url and image path. Facing issue for url link

Comment: Checked the updated answer. But what is the option to find all category text and links all together. i can do separately. But looking for the option to extract all on a single loop

Comment: the code is working fine but it extracting both for category + subcategory. Its not extracting only main categories.

Comment: So here is my final solution:

Comment: You didn't mention you want the main category only, not all the subcategories in the block. But OK, your solution will extract only the first `a` link from each block and then it's title

Answer (score 0):

So, here is my final solution what I was trying to do:

```java
List<WebElement> blocks = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".all_cat"));
for (WebElement block : blocks) {
    WebElement link = block.findElement(By.xpath(".//a"));
    String linkValue = link.getAttribute("href");
    System.out.println(linkValue);
                
    WebElement title = block.findElement(By.xpath(".//h5"));
    String titleValue = title.getText();
    System.out.println(titleValue);
}
```